# Accurate Geocode Data Using Here API

Tags: geocoding, here-api, here-autocomplete

Hellos,

I gave up on using Google Places due to the cost and decided to go with `here geocode api`. I started using [Places Search API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics_api/resource-suggest.html) which works pretty great but does not return the `lat` and `lng`.

So my solution is as follows

1. Get location Ids from the `Search API`
2. Call the geocode api by `locationId` to get the `lat` and `lng`

This solution works but is obviously slow. So my question here is

1. Is there a way to get multiple locationIds in one geocode call?
2. Is there a better service out there that is as accurate and can return lat and lng as well?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Please use [Autosuggest](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics_api/resource-autosuggest.html) instead of Places Search API.

You can find below field in **Autosuggest** API

```
  "title": "restaurant",
  "highlightedTitle": "<b>rest</b>aurant",
  "category": "restaurant",
  "href": "https://...",
  "type": "urn:nlp-types:search",
  "resultType":"category"
```

**Sample image**
[image]

Comment: The problem with autosuggest is that it requires the Lng and Lat in the query

Comment: It is the location context which is needed. You can also e.g. use a BoundingBox. Here you can find also some further explanation and a best practice chapter: https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics/location-contexts.html

Comment: @user3052526 You can pass your current location in requires lat long.

Comment: @Vivek i am trying to get a list of places as an autocomplete feature passing my location will not help

Comment: @user3052526 you can use another method like [Suggest Entrypoint](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics_api/resource-suggest.html)'' Please read full document in provided link.